# How can I make a SOQL which selects Leads filtered by a Converted Account Field not being true?

Tags: apex, soql, lead-conversion, querylocator, where

We have a requirement, after leads are converted, we are sending data to a partner about them.
We have a batch process which will periodically look for newly converted leads, send the data to the partner in bulk, and then save ConvertedAccount.Was_Sent_to_Partner__c was true for each of the saved leads.

Our query looks like this:

```
Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Id, External_Id__c
                FROM Lead
                WHERE IsConverted = TRUE
                        AND ConvertedAccountId != NULL
                        AND ConvertedAccount.Was_Sent_to_Partner__c != TRUE
        ]);
```

But the problem is, that some values have never been set, so when queried with the Developer Console's Query Editor, their value shows as `(null ConvertedAccount)` .... which aparrently is not equal to either false or null.

Is there a way I can filter on this value?

Comment: `ConvertedAccount.Was_Sent_to_Partner__c = null` or `ConvertedAccount.Was_Sent_to_Partner__c = ''` in the WHERE clause should work. I'm able to do this in my org.

Comment: @anut, `ConvertedAccount.Was_Sent_to_Partner__c` is a checkbox/boolean so '' definitely won't work.

Comment: Oops...I had tried at my end with `ConvertedAccount.Name` and missed to notice that your field `Was_Sent_to_Partner__c` is boolean. So, I guess you actually wanted the SOQL comparison on `ConvertedAccountId`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the question.  ... But it seems that the extra rows I was seeing in the developer console were false positives because the accounts did not exist anymore even though their value was not null on the lead.  I fixed the problem by changing `ConvertedAccountId != NULL` to `ConvertedAccount.Id != null`.

Comment: I was gonna suggest the same i.e., usage of `ConvertedAccount.Id`, but thought you might have that already figured that based on David's answer. So, ended my previous comment with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just what Developer Console shows when you run a relationship query and the relationship on a given row is `null`. In this situation, `ConvertedAccountId` is `null`. You can't, and shouldn't, try to filter on the `(null XXXXX)` value, because it's a UI artifact of the Developer Console.

Comment: Just reread you answer and realized an inaccuracy.  ConvertedAccount is null, but ConvertedAccountId is not null.... I would have thought that impossible and perhaps that's a defect.... but that's the heart of the problem.  However, it is fixed by checking  ConvertedAccount.Id instead of ConvertedAccountId.